# Swapping images back and forth on click in multiple places

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm creating an accordion with my own arrow icons (pngs) as the "toggle" so when you click on the down red arrow, the up blue arrow will show to collapse, and vice versa.

I got it to work with the below code, but I have multiple accordions with the same arrow icons, and I need them all to do this. When I add the same code to the other accordions (even if I changed out the ID to be unique and update it in the JS), it still only wants to toggle the first accordion.

Can anyone help me get this to work across multiple image sets (but the same images)?

HTML:

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/accordion-open.png" alt="accordion icon" id="accordion" onclick="change();"></div>
```

JS:

```
var image_tracker = 'open';

function change(){
 var image = document.getElementById('accordion');
 if(image_tracker=='open'){
 image.src='/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/accordion-close.png';
 image_tracker='close';
}
else{
 image.src='/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/accordion-open.png';
 image_tracker='open';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're assigning the listener by ID it's only going to apply to the first one. Try using a class name instead.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <img class="accordion_icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/accordion-open.png" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var open_src = "/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/accordion-open.png";
        var close_src = "/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/accordion-close.png";
        let accordion_icons = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion_icon'); // get all icons img tags
        for (let i = 0; i < accordion_icons.length; i++) {
            const element = accordion_icons[i];
            element.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{ // set listener on each one
                console.log('src was: ', event.currentTarget.src);
                event.currentTarget.src = (event.currentTarget.src == open_src ? close_src : open_src) // change the src to the one it currently isn't
                console.log('scr is now: ', event.currentTarget.src);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't even think of classes, but I tried and I'm not getting this to work. I'm adding the JS in a code snippet plugin, so does that change the code from adding it as a script into the HTML and do I need to change/add anything from the JS you provided? (Sorry, I'm still a newbie with JS).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method could be also this one, if you still want to keep the even handler in the HTML:

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/accordion-open.png" alt="accordion icon" id="accordion" onclick="change(this);"></div>
```

And in the JS:

```
function change(image){
  image.src = image.src.endsWith("open.png")
           ? image.src.replace(/open\.png$/, "close.png")
           : image.src.replace(/close\.png$/, "open.png");
}
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I'm brand-new so it doesn't show. It said it was recorded though.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!